# Графика в Builder C++

Tags: c++builder, c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как нарисовать два многоугольника и сделать так, чтобы их можно было изменять цвет и толщину контура?

Answer (score 4):

Используя Canvas и вызовы MoveTo, LineTo:

```
Graphics::TBitmap *b = new Graphics::TBitmap();

b->Canvas->Pen->Width = 1;
b->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed;

b->Canvas->MoveTo(x[0], y[0]);
// В цикле по точкам 
for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    b->Canvas->LineTo(x[i], y[i]);
```